# Building vue virtual components with vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vite, golden-layout

I'm creating a vue3 app using the golden layout library https://github.com/golden-layout/golden-layout. I followed the referenced vue3 example that uses virtual components found here https://github.com/chyj4747/vue3-golden-layout-virtualcomponent/tree/master. When I run on the vite server locally my project works fine, however when I build the project with vite build the components that are used inside golden layout do not get compiled and are not referenced correctly. The browser gives the following error: `TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module: https://<hostname>/assets/Graph.vue index-1405de76.js:1:14715`

I have tried adding the components to the dist folder but this does not work. I believe the components are not complied because they are not explicitly mentioned, however I am not sure how to get around this and how they would be loaded within golden layout after this.